How can I make this shortcode multilanguage
I'm tryng to make my shortcode multilanguage but this code is not working:
add_shortcode('periodo_affitti', 'translate_rent');

function translate_rent()
{
    global $post;

    $lang = substr(get_locale(), 0, 2);

    if ('it' != $lang)
    {
        $period_lang = get_the_author_meta('periodo_affitti_$lang', $post->post_author);
        
        if (!empty($period_lang)) {
            return $period_lang;
        } else {
            return $period_lang;
        }
        
    } else {
        return $period_lang;
    }

} 


use " instead of ' to evaluate variable in string "periodo_affitti_$lang". https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

ok, it works! I just needed to create another variable for the italian version, because it's not "periodo _affitti_it", but just "periodo_affitti"
